# python modules hidden though init.py is used

Tags: python, python-import

In one of my projects, i have a main directory (say Directory_XYZ) which has 4 sub directories "config", "source", "library" and "modules". All four have python modules which need to talk to each other. I have placed empty `__init__.py` in all four sub directories. But still some modules are hidden from each other. Any help is appreciated.

I am setting the sys path like this in all the python modules under all sub directories.

```
lib_path = os.path.abspath('../modules')
lib_path1 = os.path.abspath('../source')
lib_path2 = os.path.abspath('../library')
lib_path3 = os.path.abspath('../config')
sys.path.append(lib_path)
sys.path.append(lib_path1)
sys.path.append(lib_path2)
sys.path.append(lib_path3)
```

When I am importing ABC.py from "modules" sub directory in PQR.py under "source" subdirectory, it is hidden.

PQR.py has above sys path code and below import code.

```
from ABC import *
```

Am i doing it wrong?

Comment: What's the relation between `ABC` and `XYZ`?

Comment: ABC and XYZ are 2 different python modules in differnt directories. Some of the functions defined under ABC is used by XYZ. Hence i need to import ABC into XYZ.

Answer (score 0):

The blank file needs to be named `__init__.py`. Try that, if it still doesn't work, leave a comment.

Comment: It has to be `__init__.py` though

Answer (score 0):

First of all note that the name of the file hinting `Python` that a specified directory is indeed a package that may be imported is `__init__.py` and not `init.py`. That is, `__init__.py` with 2 leading underscores and 2 enclosing underscores before the `.py` suffix.

Now, in order to solve your issue, all you need to do is to add `XYZ` to `sys.path` (not required if `XYZ` is in your current directory), and place an empty `__init__.py` file under it too. The four packages under `XYZ` should also contain an empty `__init__.py` file, as you have correctly done, but there is no need to add their path to `sys.path`.

Then you will be able to access your modules from within each other in the following manner:

```
from XYZ.modules import <specific-module>
from XYZ.source import <specific-module>
```

If you want a specific module to be automatically imported when its package is imported with `from package import *`, you have to update that package's `__init__.py` file to define `__all__` as a list that includes the desired module's name, in the following manner:

```
__all__ = ["<specific-module-1>", "<specific-module-2>"]
```

Once that is done, just importing the package containing that `__init__.py` file, also imports the specified modules. For example, if the `modules` directory contains the modules `X` and `Y` and an `__init__.py` file that defines:

```
__all__ = ['X']
```

then the statement `from XYZ.modules import *` automatically imports 'X' as well and makes it available in the importing module's namespace as `X`.

I suggest you read [Python's tutorial regarding modules and packages](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) and [Python's documentation on the import statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement).
[This blog post](http://blog.habnab.it/blog/2013/07/21/python-packages-and-you/) is also an interesting read.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply Yoel! But I didnt understand some things. ABC.py is the python file and "modules" is the directory where it resides. SO should it not be from modules.ABC import * ?

Comment: Since i have already added "modules" in my path and have __init__.py as well, I thought i should be able to see ABC.py and all the functions under it when i do "from ABC import *". I also tried "from modules.ABC import *" but i get the error "ImportError: No module named modules.ABC"

Comment: Please see my updated answer. You should verify that `XYZ` is in `sys.path` or that it's your current directory. Once that is the case, you should be able to perform `from XYZ.modules import ABC` or `from XYZ.modules.ABC import *`.